# React Native Android on Mac Os

Tags: android, macos, react-native, flipper

I'm having issues running my react-native project for Android. Below is my output of my project.

```
System:
  OS: macOS 10.15.5
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5287U CPU @ 2.90GHz
  Memory: 1.33 GB / 8.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 13.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  npm: 6.13.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
  Platforms: iOS 14.4, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
IDEs:
  Xcode: 12.4/12D4e - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
  react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native: 0.61.5
```

The error I'm facing is.

```
2021-03-02 19:15:51.950 8696-8746/com.xxxx D/SoLoader: libflipper.so not found on /data/user/0/com.xxxx/lib-main
2021-03-02 19:15:51.950 8696-8746/com.xxxx D/SoLoader: libflipper.so found on /data/app/~~JKMOYC8Kgh_0cyeIIIPfJw==/com.xxxx-A59UUF7pLW4jtdMOS9BPnQ==/lib/x86
2021-03-02 19:15:51.950 8696-8746/com.xxxx D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libflipper.so
2021-03-02 19:15:51.953 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libfbjni.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~JKMOYC8Kgh_0cyeIIIPfJw==/com.xxxx-A59UUF7pLW4jtdMOS9BPnQ==/lib/x86/libflipper.so in namespace classloader-namespace
2021-03-02 19:15:51.953 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:939)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.953 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1628)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.953 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$1.load(SoLoader.java:395)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibraryFrom(DirectorySoSource.java:77)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource.loadLibrary(DirectorySoSource.java:50)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.ApplicationSoSource.loadLibrary(ApplicationSoSource.java:82)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:766)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:673)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:611)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:559)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.flipper.android.EventBase.<clinit>(EventBase.java:19)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.954 8696-8746/com.xxxx W/System.err:     at com.facebook.flipper.android.FlipperThread.run(FlipperThread.java:25)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.955 8696-8746/com.xxxx E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libflipper.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libfbjni.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~JKMOYC8Kgh_0cyeIIIPfJw==/com.xxxx-A59UUF7pLW4jtdMOS9BPnQ==/lib/x86/libflipper.so in namespace classloader-namespace result: 0
2021-03-02 19:15:51.956 8696-8747/com.xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: 
FlipperConnectionThread
   Process: com.xxxx, PID: 8696
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <clinit> failed for class com.facebook.flipper.android.EventBase; see exception in other thread
    at com.facebook.flipper.android.FlipperThread.run(FlipperThread.java:25)
2021-03-02 19:15:51.959 8696-8746/com.xxxx I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8696 SIG: 9
```

I have gone through as many bug reports as i can [Crashes on emulator #707](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/707), [SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libflipperfb.so #515](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/515)
, [couldn't find DSO to load:](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28750) and several others.

I have tried running the following commands

rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/

cd android && ./gradlew clean

As well as Build -> Clean from my Android Studio (Android Studio 4.1.1). However when I try run the app it still fails.

Tried changing my Flipper version from FLIPPER_VERSION=0.33.1 -> FLIPPER_VERSION=0.78.0 in my gradle.properties but still it didn't work.